# What does a function being globally Lipschitz mean?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

I'm failling to see how a function being globally Lipschitz on a variable in a set  is any different from saying that the function has bounded continuous (partial) derivatives on that variable.

Could someone give me some intuition about what means for a function to be Lipschitz?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to know the relation between the two properties or something else?

Comment: Try to imagine a function that is Lipschitz but not differentiable, at least at some points.

Comment: A first difference is that a Lipschitz function has no reason to have partial derivatives. A classic example is $f(x)=|x|$, which is $1$-Lipschitz but not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct...almost everywhere.  This is due to [Rademacher's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher's_theorem) theorem.  However, as mentioned in the comments, there are plenty of Lipschitz functions that are not differentiable, like $f(x) = \vert x\vert$.  In fact, there are even functions with infinitely many nondifferentiable points that are still Lipschitz!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is differentiable on an interval in one variable, then $f$ is Lipschitz $1$ on that domain iff $f'$ is bounded there. In several variables the situation is different: For example, $f(x,y) = \arg (x+iy)$ on $\{1< x^2 + y^2<2\} \setminus (-\infty,0],$ where $\arg z$ the principal value argument.